# Method wont grab StructureArray

Tags: c#, arrays, structure

Im quite new to structs so i appreciate any help you guys give.
The problem i have is that i dont know how i can make it so that the method ShowPokeBox actually gets the Array by Parameter. I tried Puting Pokemon.Array into the Parameter for ShowPokeBox but i couldnt get that to work as well.

Program runs as expected except for the ShowPokeBox. It doesnt inculte any data at all.

Thanks in advance.

```
namespace StructArrays

struct Pokemon{

    public int health;
    public string name;
    public string author; }





class Program
{

    public static void PokeBox(int PokeAnzahl)
    {
        Pokemon[] PokeBox = new Pokemon[PokeAnzahl];

        Console.WriteLine("Enter {0} different Pokemons: ", PokeAnzahl);

        for (int i = 0; i < PokeAnzahl; i++)
        {

            PokeBox[i] = new Pokemon();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter Health Points: ");
            PokeBox[i].health = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Enter Pokemon Name: ");
            PokeBox[i].name = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter Author of Pokemon: ");
            PokeBox[i].author = Console.ReadLine();
        }

    }

    public static void ShowPokeBox(int PokeAnzahl)
    {
        Pokemon[] PokeBox = new Pokemon[PokeAnzahl];

        for (int i = 0; i < PokeAnzahl; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Pokemon Nr. {0}  Name: {1} HP: {2} Author: {3}", i,  PokeBox[i].name, PokeBox[i].health, PokeBox[i].author);
        }

    }


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int PokeAnzahl;

        Console.WriteLine("How many Pokemons do you want to create?: ");
        PokeAnzahl = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        PokeBox(PokeAnzahl);
        ShowPokeBox(PokeAnzahl);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }




}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are constructing two completely separate arrays of Pokemon, one when reading from input, and another when attempting to display the input data. ShowPokeBox() needs a reference to the same Pokemon[] that's created and populated in PokeBox().

i would suggest returning the Pokemon[] from PokeBox(), and then passing it into ShowPokeBox()...

```
public static Pokemon[] PokeBox(int PokeAnzahl)
{
    Pokemon[] Pokemons = new Pokemon[PokeAnzahl];

    Console.WriteLine("Enter {0} different Pokemons: ", PokeAnzahl);

    for (int i = 0; i < PokeAnzahl; i++)
    {
         ...
    }

    return Pokemons;
}

public static void ShowPokeBox(Pokemon[] Pokemons)
{
    ...
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ...
    var Pokemons = PokeBox(PokeAnzahl);
    ShowPokeBox(Pokemons);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!. I  never used "var" before and i didnt really know for what it is used but now i know!.

Comment: Try not to over use it. My usage above is not great, used for speed only. It's good if it does not make the type of the variable hard to see in the code. Good usage is like: "var myVar = new MyCoolObject();".  Not so great usage: "var myVar = DoSomeRandomStuff();" I use it a lot in test code, and mostly avoid it in production code.

Comment: I just realized something while overlooking my code. If you look at the for loop in the Method Pokebox you can see that at the beginning i created a new Pokemon(); . I didnt rly understand why i needed that and tried running the code without that one line and it worked perfectly. Is there any benefit in creating a new Pokemon everytime the for array loops?.

Comment: Actually no, assuming the initialized state should be all zeroes. The structures in the array are automatically zero-initialized by the framework,